# Getting addEventListener error while writing test cases in jest

Tags: reactjs, ts-jest

In my react project, I got the below error while writing test cases for a component where I implemented the below Code to get Domain actions by Passing required props.

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener  at node_modules\\@restart\\hooks\\cjs\\useEventListener.js:21:12
```

My DomainAction.tsx

```
import React, { forwardRef, useState } from "react";
import Dropdown from "react-bootstrap/Dropdown";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { ReactComponent as Bar } from "../../assets/custom-icons/bars.svg";
import { fetchDomainActions } from "../utility";

export interface DomainActionProps {
  domainObjectId: string | number;
  domainClassName?: string;
  domainActionTypeIdentifier: any;
  domainActionArguments: any;
}
type CustomToggleProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  onClick: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLSpanElement, MouseEvent>) => void;
  onClickHandler: () => void;
};
const CustomToggle = forwardRef<HTMLSpanElement, CustomToggleProps>(
  ({ children, onClick, onClickHandler }, ref) => (
    <span
      className="context-menu-icon"
      ref={ref}
      onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        onClick(e);
        onClickHandler();
      }}
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      {children}
    </span>
  )
);

const DomainAction: React.FC<DomainActionProps> = ({
  domainObjectId,
  domainClassName,
  domainActionTypeIdentifier,
  domainActionArguments
}) => {
  const [domainActions, setDomainActions] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  let domainActionsList: React.JSX.Element[] | null = null;

  if (domainActions.length === 0) {
    domainActionsList = [];
  } else {
    domainActionsList = domainActions.map((domainAction) => {
      let domainActionElement: React.JSX.Element | null = null;
      if (domainAction.domainActionName === "noDomainAction") {
        domainActionElement = (
          <Dropdown.Item
            as="span"
            key={domainAction.domainActionName}
            data-testid={domainAction.name}
            eventKey={domainAction.domainActionName}
          >
            {domainAction.name}
          </Dropdown.Item>
        );
      } else {
        let attr: Record<string, any> | null = null;

        if (
          domainActionTypeIdentifier &&
          domainActionTypeIdentifier[domainAction.domainActionName]?.uri
        ) {
          let to =
            domainActionTypeIdentifier[domainAction.domainActionName].uri;

          if (
            domainActionTypeIdentifier[domainAction.domainActionName]
              ?.hasPathParamId
          ) {
            to += domainObjectId;
          }

          attr = {
            as: Link,
            to: to
          };
        } else {
          attr = {
            as: "span",
            onClick: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLSpanElement, MouseEvent>) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              domainActionTypeIdentifier[domainAction.domainActionName]?.fn(
                domainObjectId
              );
            }
          };
        }

        domainActionElement = (
          <Dropdown.Item
            key={domainAction.domainActionName}
            {...attr}
            data-testid={domainAction.name}
            eventKey={domainAction.domainActionName}
          >
            {domainAction.name}
          </Dropdown.Item>
        );
      }

      return domainActionElement;
    });
  }

  const onClickHandler = () => {
    if (!isLoaded) {
      fetchDomainActions(
        { domainObjectId, domainClassName, domainActionArguments },
        setDomainActions
      );
      setIsLoaded(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Dropdown
      align="start"
      drop="start"
      className="fc-domain-action"
      data-testid="domainActionDropDown"
    >
      <Dropdown.Toggle
        as={CustomToggle}
        id="dropdown-custom-components"
        onClickHandler={onClickHandler}
      >
        {/* <i className="fa fa-bars-sort fa-2x" /> */}
        <Bar data-testid="domainAction" />
      </Dropdown.Toggle>
      <Dropdown.Menu>{domainActionsList}</Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

export default DomainAction;
```

Tried mocking useEventListener but didn't work out. I need to fire click event after getting domain actions.

```
const addEventListenerMock = jest.fn();
const removeEventListenerMock = jest.fn();

jest.doMock("@restart/hooks", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("@restart/hooks"),
  useEventListener: (target: any, event: any, handler: any) => {
    addEventListenerMock(target, event, handler);
    return () => {
      removeEventListenerMock(target, event, handler);
    };
  }
}));
```

Looks like the error is at Dropdown.js file in react-bootstrap where it used useEventListener function. I also tried my mocking that component from bootstrap package, but not solved.